# Making this post more clear?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed

[How accurate is the portrayal of Leonardo Da Vinci in Voyager](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/37697/how-accurate-is-the-portrayal-of-leonardo-da-vinci-in-voyager)

How do I make this more "clear", I engaged with the question asked in the comments but it the got closed with no information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current form, the question is impossible to answer without being familiar with the portrayal, i.e. having watched the TV episode. This kind of question is a better fit at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/. Here, it's unreasonable to assume people have watched a non-history-related TV show.

Otherwise, you should pick specific claims that can be proven or disproven. The culture on this stack tends to be harsher on opinion-based, personal conjecture, so focusing on specific, true/false claims will do better.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The Sci-Fi SE may well consider the question too historical but I will try posting it there. I cannot expect more than a small proportion here to be familiar with the episode and be able to answer the question, but then that is often the case with SE questions anyway. How closely personality traits match is unfortunately unavoidably at least somewhat subjective, I guess for example the accuracy of portrayals in period films would be off topic as well. I cannot fix the subjectiveness without making the question unhelpfully specific.

Comment: There seems to be controversy on the SCI FI SE as to how social he was, if anyone here wants to add that info there.